# How can I rename the local kernel without causing issues?

Tags: kernel

I would like to name my kernels. However when I remove "Local" Mathematica becomes unstable, sometimes crashes sometimes doesn't initialize correctly. 
[image]
Is there something special about the name "Local"?

Comment: Probably because "Local" is the default for new notebooks.

Comment: @Szabolcs is there a way to change that?

Comment: *Mathematica* 10.0.2 appears to not let me remove or rename **Local** -- which version are you using and how did you remove **Local**?

Comment: I don't know.  To be honest, I don't really see the point of doing this.  If it breaks Mathematica, don't do it.